# Nuxt crashes when I try to save scss files

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm building a project using NuxtJS it was working perfectly but suddenly when I try to save any scss file it crashes and give me the below error

```
Nuxt Fatal Error

Error: acorn-private-class-elements does not support mixing different acorn copies
```

I tried to remove node_modules and package.lock, also I cleared cache but nothing works, Please advise.

Comment: This is not an scss error but, as the error message also says, a problem with acorn-private-class-elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure in your config file you set your scss.

```
  css: [
    '~/static/css/main.scss'
  ],
```

Also take a look over here:
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2878

Comment: config is set correctly, also i tried the solution in the link it not works, it's the same